# NameError: global name 'styles' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

This part of my code `Paragraph('Road',style["Normal"], bulletText=None)` gives me this `NameError: global name 'styles' is not defined.`
The module that I have importeded is :

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
```

Comment: is it `styles is not defined`, or `style is not defined` ?

Comment: style is not defined.

Comment: do you have a dictionary ? (style={} )

Comment: No, its just the style["Normal"]

Comment: it is expecting a dictionary `style` , and looking for the key `'Normal'` within that dictionary

Comment: so something like this? d = {1: "Normal", 2: "Center"}

Comment: yeah.. if you use `d` as the dict name, change to `d['Normal']`

Comment: Thanks, that worked I just set style = getSampleStyleSheet()

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have defined styles like this :

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
```

Also you can add other styles like "Justify"
You can do it this way (exemple with "Justify"):

```
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY

styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
text = "Hello World !"
story.append(Paragraph(text, style["Justify"]))
```

Then use it this way :

```
# create pdf
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate("your_doc.pdf")
# write in it
story = []
story.append(Paragraph(text, style["Justify"]))    
# save it
pdf.build(story)
# return
return (frame)
```

And Here it is you have your pdf with styles !